# How to save Result/score of Jquizzy Jquery Quize Engine in mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm try to save the result/score of JQuizzy Jquery Quiz System into MySql database.
My requirement is to send the result through jquery to a php file(save.php)and there I'll able to save the result into database.

Please anybody help me for sending the result .

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think first off you should google for some simple ajax examples, but to ease it up for you, you should be able to do it with something similar to this..

Javascript mockup - [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zMvPJ/5/)
PHP mockup - [CodePad](http://codepad.org/7i2XWqVn)

Mind that these are just examples of how to do it. The php script is very basic and insecure, you should look into more JavaScript and PHP if you have little experience in those as using insecure code like this would render your application vulnerable to attacks.

Cheers and hope this helps!

--Matīss